# jQuery add clickable letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am trying to make the C in my jQuery-added span element clickable, and I want it to change to F when clicked, but for some reason it isn't working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
    $("#location").html("<b>New York, NY</b>");
    $("#temperature").html("112");
    $("#temperature").append("<span> C </span>");
    $("span:contains('C')").attr("id", "type");  
    $("span:contains('C')").click(changeNotation());
});
    
function changeNotation(){
    var notation = document.getElementById("type");
    if(notation.textContent == 'C')
        notation.innerHTML = 'F';
    else if(notation.textContent == 'F')
        notation.innerHTML = 'C';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center well">
        <h2 class="text-info"> Welcome to the <span><b>Weather App!</span></b></h2>
        <p class="text-primary bg-info text-center">
          This app will display the weather based on your current location. Click on the C or F to toggle between celcius and fahrenheit.</p>
        <h2 class="text-center text-info"><b> Current location </b></h2>
        <h1 class="text-center text-info" id="location"> </h1> 
        <h2 class="text-center text-info"> <b>Current Temperature</b> </h2>
        <h1 class="text-center text-info" id='temperature'> </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also you need make `<tagA><tagB></tagB></tagA>`. I'm telling about <span><b>Weather App!</span></b>

Comment: and to add onclick event in jquery you need to make `$("span:contains('C')").on('click', changeNotation);`

Comment: and add `span` with "C"

Comment: Could be because you aren't delegating the event further up the DOM? Whenever you dynamically add DOM elements, the jQuery bindings you made on page load won't apply to the new elements unless you bind them to something that exists on page load, like `body`. So, like: `$("body").on("click", "span:contains('C')", function() {  do your function stuff  });`.

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion  but  unfortunately still does not work. Could it be the changeNotation function itself? I think I tried by putting the same code in HTML instead of jQuery with a button element and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , *personally I don't prefer to see pure js with jquery*

**About your code:**

1- ًWhen using append you need to delegate event by using

```
$("#temperature").on('click',"span#type", changeNotation);
```

2- You need to use `span#type` on click event not `span:contains('C')` in your case it will change just when contain C not when contain F

**the next code will help**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#location").html("<b>New York, NY</b>");
  $("#temperature").html("112").append('<span id="type"> C </span>');
  $("#temperature").on('click',"span#type", changeNotation);
});

function changeNotation(){
 var el = $("#type"),
       notation = $("#type").text().trim();
  if( notation == 'C'){
      el.html('F');
  }else if(notation == 'F'){
      el.html('C');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center well">
    <h2 class="text-info"> Welcome to the <span><b>Weather App!</span></b></h2>
    <p class="text-primary bg-info text-center">
      This app will display the weather based on your current location. Click on the C or F to toggle between celcius and fahrenheit.</p>
    <h2 class="text-center text-info"><b> Current location </b></h2>
      <h1 class="text-center text-info" id="location"> </h1> 
    <h2 class="text-center text-info"> <b>Current Temperature</b> </h2>
      <h1 class="text-center text-info" id='temperature'> </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

3- If you just need to change C to F you can use

```
$("#temperature").on('click',"span#type:contains('C')", changeNotation);
```

and for contains F you will need another click event

```
$("#temperature").on('click',"span#type:contains('F')", AnotherFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this solved it and very informative!

Comment: @Philosopho You're Welcome. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, you should use `$(document).on("click", "#type", function() { changeNotation(); });`. The selector should be based on the id or when it changes to 'F' it wont exist.

Additionally, you should use trim() when comparing the values `if(notation.textContent.trim() == 'C')`